# "java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header" from ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, exception, objectinputstream

I'm trying to create an ObjectInputStream from a BufferedInputStream created from a socket's inputstream. When I initialize the variable, it throws the StreamCorruptedException due to an invalid stream header. I tried searching and other solutions said that it was due to using different kinds of stream readers. In my code, all my Object I/O Streams use the same format.

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Server server = new Server("Room", "Server");
    Client client = new Client("Client", "localhost");

    server.start();
    client.start();

    Message m = new Message();
    m.addValue("Message", "Dummy Text");
    client.transmit(m);


}
```

Server listener :

```
    private void startServerListener() {

    while (true) {

        try {

            ObjectOutputStream writer;
            ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream())); // Exception points here

            Message msg = (Message) reader.readObject();
            System.out.println(3);
            if (msg.hasValue("Username")) {
                System.out.println(4);
                this.username = msg.getValue("Username");
                msg.remove("Username");
                Message tmp_msg = new Message();
                tmp_msg.addValue("Raw Message", username + " has joined");

                for (Listener l : Server.clients) {

                    Socket socket = l.getSocket();
                    writer = new ObjectOutputStream(
                            new BufferedOutputStream(
                                    socket.getOutputStream()));
                    writer.writeObject(tmp_msg);
                    writer.flush();

                }

            }
            if (msg.hasValue("Message")) {
                System.out.println(5);
                for (Listener l : Server.clients) {

                    Socket socket = l.getSocket();
                    writer = new ObjectOutputStream(
                            new BufferedOutputStream(
                                    socket.getOutputStream()));
                    writer.writeObject(msg.getValue("Message"));
                    writer.flush();

                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Client that sends the data :

```
private String username, ip;
private ObjectOutputStream writer;

public Socket socket;

public Client(String username, String ip) {

    this.username = username;
    this.ip = ip;

}

@Override
public synchronized void run() {

    try {

        socket = new Socket(ip, 22600);
        writer = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.addValue("Username", username);
        writer.writeObject(msg);
        writer.flush();
        Listener listener = new Listener(socket, Client.class);
        System.out.println(0);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public synchronized void transmit(Message msg) {

    try {

        System.out.println("a");
        System.out.println(1);
        writer.writeObject(msg);
        writer.flush();
        System.out.println(2);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Stack trace :

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7371007E
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.Listener.startServerListener(Listener.java:89)
at com.Listener.access$1(Listener.java:82)
at com.Listener$2.run(Listener.java:37)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Where is the client code?

Comment: Ok I editted it. It's there now

Comment: Where are you actually calling transmit or run? Why you have 2 methods that actually send a message?

Comment: I call run in my main method via Thread.start() and then I call transmit after. The run one is more of an initial data packet to be sent to the server containing the client's username. This is the automated part. The transmit is supposed to be for manually created messages e.g. something the client wants to send

Comment: Ok the main method's there now.